# Connect Tableau and KoBoToolbox

Tags: tableau

Is it possible to **connect kobotoolbox to tableau** in any way?
Any kind of method would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that Kobol offers a REST API. Thus, one could create WebDataConnector to fetch the data in Tableau. If that's an overkill, you could write a script in e.g. Python which extracts the data from the REST API and creates a csv file.

REST API
http://support.kobotoolbox.org/en/articles/592398-api-and-rest-services

REST API -> Tableau
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1y5LsqQd00s&list=WL&index=2&t=0s